# executing foreach loop only once

Tags: php, foreach

As we know foreach loop will execute till condition does not become false.
I want to execute it only once.

```
$i=0;
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
{    

       if($i!=0)  
          break;
       $logo= $element->src . '<br>';
       $i++;
}
```

Is there any other solution for this? like `foronce` in place of `foreach`?

Comment: There is, just put a `break` at the end of the block. But instead of doing this just get the one item you want out of the collection instead of "looping once".

Comment: What. I don't understand. Just don't... loop? `$img = $html->find('img'); $img[0] = $foo`

Comment: Why do you need a loop? `$logo = $html->find('img')[0]->src;`

Comment: `"till condition does not become false"`? would be better phrased as `"While condition is true"`

Comment: foreach traverses each element __once__ it does not loop. Read the [fine manual](http://fi1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: `foreach` is a construct . Not a loop.

Comment: Doing something once for each element in a sequence is what pretty much everyone calls a "loop".

Comment: I came to this looking for a provisional change, just for debugging purposes in order to change the code as minimum. This means i want to use the array-element structure just for the debugging without having to write breaks or so.
So maybe its easy to solve, its bad for proggraming, but it might have a point in a rare case

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> As we know foreach loop will execute till condition does not become false.

A `foreach` loop will execute once for every item of the container unless a `return` or `break` condition is defined within the `foreach` block.

> I want to execute it only once.

Loops that executes once are called "don't use a loop in the first place". Here's your example fixed:

```
$logo = $html->find('img')[0]->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: >> Loops that executes once are called "don't use a loop in the first place". I love the way you talk !!!